# How to change the Current Working Directory of Maui Blazor App

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

I have a Maui Blazor Hybrid apps created through Visual Studio 2022. When I access the method GetCurrentDirectory() this returns C:/Windows/system32.

How do I set this to return the path of where the wwwroot folder is of my project?

Comment: Why do you need to know the root path?

Comment: I'm using Xmldocument.load() and when I apply a relative path, for some weird reason it is appending "C:\Windows\System32" to the beginning of it. I would like the relative path in the hopes that have a full path to the xml file it won't append anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use the `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` to set the application's current working directory to the specified directory according to [this method's official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=net-7.0).

And then, you can get the **wwwroot folder** by the following code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot");
```

So you can change the Current Working Directory by the following code:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "wwwroot"));
```

Comment: This certainly could work if I just give it a path I know will work, but the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory variable returns "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX" which is not the wwwroot directory I need. Everything before the bin directory is correct so I could split it from there I suppose.

Comment: But this is the really physical path of the wwwroot directory. And the path before the bin directory is the project's path which was set when you created the project with the visual studio. In addition, you may can try to use the [App data directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#app-data-directory) instead of the wwwroot directory. @DaveK

Comment: You can check the official document about [the wwwroot file in the .net maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-maui). @DaveK

Comment: Am I then to make sure my wwwroot material is in the bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX directory? I suppose that's not that hard to do.

Comment: It should be in the path, but when you package and publish it, the wwwroot material should in your app package. So I sugest you use the app data directory. @DaveK